# Time Calculation in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I am developing an app for Towing the broken up vehicles. Where a towing driver places a bid. In his bid there are two fields wrapupTime (32 mins) and eta (15 mins). On the basis of these two i have to calculate bidTime (Another attribute). But i could not figured out how to do it. here is my bid schema.

```
bidsSchema = new Schema({

details: {
    type: String
},
dispatcher: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: "users"
},
bidAmount: {
    type: Number
},
wrapupTime: {
    type: String
},
eta: {
    type: String
},
bidTime: {
    type: String
}, 
driver: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: "users"
},
truck: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: "trucks"
}, 
decliningJobReason: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['too far', 'pricing', 'busy', 'other'],
}
},
{
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' }
});
```

I have tried to add the `wrapupTime: { type: String }, eta: { type: String },` and save it into `bidTime` with the momentjs. The time is in the form of strings like 15 mins, 20 mins. But don't found any good solution. Please guide.

Comment: I can recommend you to do math on time with the Date() method and Date.now() which gives you the time in milliseconds since 1.1.1970. Then you can precisely add and subtract times from the current time (now), and present it with momentjs as "In 2,5 hours" or "4 minutes from now" etc. Note that moment JS is deprecated. You should use Day.js or Luxon or similar (https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

save it in miliseconds, not in dates, if you need to do calculations and get other dates based on those offsets, you can just get the date in milliseconds, add the ms from the offset, and create a new Date object using the milliseconds (timestamp).

```
const time_for_date = 1615200498841;
const date_from_time = new Date(time_for_date);

console.log(date_from_time) // It should print the date in some default format.
```